# how to interact with cisco call manager using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cisco

we are developing an IVR based web application using node js.

is it possible to interact with cisco unified call manager from my web application using node js?

Answer (score 0):

As per my information, Cisco unified communication manager provides one medium for integration which is Jtapi. Through JTAPI you can control agents states, Call control etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use the built-in AXL commands which is a SOAP based API. 
https://developer.cisco.com/site/axl/